# ReadFile works fine inside VS C++ IDE but fails stand-alone

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, pipe, inter-process-communicat

Currently I have two apps, one with a GUI (written using MFC) and the other as a standard executable. The GUI app (parent) triggers the standard app (child) using `CreateProcessW` call and parent receives messages from its child via an anonymous pipe. The message receiving process works fine when I run the parent inside the VS IDE. However, if I run the parent standalone, parent does not receive any messages from its child (i.e. parent get hang in ReadFile call, waiting for messages).

Any thoughts on this?

Note: After creation of anonymous pipe, all read operations happens inside a separate thread and it does not block either UI or main thread. Some code related to child process creation and used parameters are given below.

```
// pipe creation code
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr; 
// Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited.  
saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 

// Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. 
if ( ! CreatePipe(&m_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &m_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0) )
{
    m_logger->log( __FILE__, __LINE__, EventSeverity::WARNING, "Pipe cannot be created, will not receive meassages from child processes" );
}

// Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.
if ( ! SetHandleInformation(m_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) )
{
    m_logger->log( __FILE__, __LINE__, EventSeverity::WARNING, "Could not make the read handler of the anonymous pipe not-inheritable" );
}

SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, m_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);
SetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE, m_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);

//Child process creation code
m_startupInfo.lpDesktop   = NULL;
m_startupInfo.lpReserved  = NULL;
m_startupInfo.lpReserved2 = NULL;
m_startupInfo.lpTitle     = NULL;
m_startupInfo.hStdError   = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
m_startupInfo.hStdOutput  = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
m_startupInfo.dwFlags     = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW|STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
m_startupInfo.cb          = sizeof( m_startupInfo ); 

// launch the executable
m_isExecuting = CreateProcessW( app.exe,     // lpApplicationName
                                m_pwszParam,                                     // lpCommandLine
                                0,                                               // lpProcessAttributes
                                0,                                               // lpThreadAttributes
                                TRUE,                                            // bInheritHandles
                                CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP,                        // dwCreationFlags
                                NULL,                                            // lpEnvironment
                                curent working directory // lpCurrentDirectory
                                &m_startupInfo,                                  // lpStartupInfo
                                &m_processInfo                                   // lpProcessInformation
                              );
```

Comment: Does the child process actually run? Maybe the current directory is wrong. What error checking are you doing?

Comment: @JonathanPotter yes it runs. I can observe it in the Task Manager.

Comment: I did further testing on this and what I can see is, when parent runs standalone child writes data to the console rather re-directing them (as a result reading thread in parent hangs waiting for data). But inside IDE this works fine. Very Weired!!!!

Answer (score 0):

managed to solve this issue. Previously I was updating parent's output and error handlers to newly created handlers in order to retrieve them when creating a child process. However, this doesn't seem to be working. When I modify the code to pass the pipe handlers via a pointer or a reference then things started to work fine.

However this does not explain the reason for running inside IDE and failing it in stand-alone mode.

```
//set the handler
SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, m_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);
SetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE, m_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);

//get the handler
m_startupInfo.hStdError   = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
m_startupInfo.hStdOutput  = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
```